# ngAnnotate does not annotate and overwrite files like it should

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs

I'm trying to use grunt-ng-annotate in my build, and my files don't seem to be annotated when I view them.

```
ngAnnotate: {
  options: {
    singleQuotes: true
  },
  dist: {
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      cwd: '.tmp/concat/scripts',
      src: '*.js',
      dest: '.tmp/concat/scripts'
    }]
  }
},
```

However, if I add:

```
      ext: '.annotated.js',
```

Then I can see the annotation in the file. It appears that somehow, it just doesn't want to overwrite the old files, unless I name them something different. What's the deal here?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem today as well. I decided to post solution for myself, because I really struggled with this and thought maybe someone else may need this at some point. So what I had to do was set remove and add options for ngAnnotate, so it can remove and add annotated items like this:

```
   ngAnnotate: {
       options: {
           remove: true,
           add: true
       },
       dist: {
           files: [{
                   expand: true,
                   sourceMap: true,
                   src: 'src/js/**/*.js',
               }],
       }
   },
```